# extracting list of xml files from tar.gz file from ftp server

Tags: python, xml, ftp, gzip, tarfile

I need to extract a list of xml files that are in a tar.gz file that I'm trying to read.

I tried this:

```
import os
from ftplib import FTP

def writeline(data):
    filedata.write(data)
    filedata.write(os.linesep)

ftp = FTP('ftp.my.domain.com')
ftp.login(user="username",passwd="password")
ftp.cwd('inner_folder')
filedata = open('mytargz.tar.gz', 'w')
ftp.retrlines('RETR %s' % ftp.nlst()[0], writeline)
```

I used `ftp.nlst()[0]` because I have a list of tar.gz files in my ftp.
It looks like the `data` that I'm receiving in my `writeline` callback is some weird symbols, and than the `filedata.write(data)` is throwing an error:
`{UnicodeEncodeError}'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x8b' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>`.
I can really use some help here..

Comment: what you want is the [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) notice that you can pass it a file object so read your ftp into a byteIO  `io.BytesIO(my_bytes)`

Comment: yes, I assumed It's wrong, but the ```data``` I'm receiving is a string of strange symbols, so I'm getting an error ```a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'```..it seems that something is wrong there, before I'm unzipping my file.

Comment: nothing is wrong with the "string". you are receiving bytes, its not text, you cant print like it was text

Comment: the ```io.BytesIO(data)``` is throwing the error ```a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'```

Comment: i see the issue, you use `retrlines` instead of `retrbinary` and when you open your file open it with `'wb'` for write binary and not `'w'`

Comment: I did use ```retrlines``` and I tried to change the ```'w'``` to ```'wb'```.. still the same error

Comment: use `retrbinary`

Comment: ```io.BytesIO(data)``` is reading my bytes to the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont have an ftp server to try this with, but this should work:

```
import os
from ftplib import FTP

def writeline(data):
    filedata.write(data)

ftp = FTP('ftp.my.domain.com')
ftp.login(user="username",passwd="password")
ftp.cwd('inner_folder')
filedata = open('mytargz.tar.gz', 'wb')
ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % ftp.nlst()[0], writeline)
```

note that we open the file with write binary `'wb'` and we ask the ftp to return binary and not text and that our callback function only write without adding seperators

Comment: After doing all this, in the ```writeline``` method I added :
```tarfile.open('my_tar_gz.tar.gz', "r:gz").extractall("xmls")```
for extracting my files from the```my_tar_gz.tar.gz``` file.  I saw that the file has data - a few xml files, do you know maybe what can be the reason for the  ```tarfile.open``` command to throw ```ReadError: empty file```?

Comment: how do you know the file has data? you opened it with an external program?

Comment: if the error is coming from tarfile.open() then the only thing i can think of is that you are accidentally opening the wrong file. to the best of my knowledge that error will not pop up on a valid, non-empty file